# Listening websocket in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, websocket

I'm using MVC 4. I have a js code that needs to communicate with the server with the help of Websockets. I'm using [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) at the server. I'm creating the socket server in `Application_Start` event. But when I try the connection from browser console, I get errors like `Connection refused`.

Here is my `global.asax` code.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{       
    IPAddress ip = null;
    if (GetResolvedConnecionIPAddress(out ip)) // Get host ip
    {
        string Domain = "wss" + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + ip + ":" + "8092"; 

        FleckLog.Level = Fleck.LogLevel.Debug;

        try
        {
            if (GetResolvedConnecionIPAddress(out ip))
            {

                var server = new WebSocketServer(Domain);

                server.Start(socket =>
                {
                    LogWriter.Logger.Info("WS: Inside socket server");
                    socket.OnOpen = () =>
                    {
                        LogWriter.Logger.Info("WS: OnOpen socket");
                    };
                    socket.OnClose = () =>
                    {
                        LogWriter.Logger.Info("WS: OnClose socket");
                    };
                    socket.OnMessage = message =>
                    {
                        LogWriter.Logger.Info("WS: OnMsg socket");
                    };
                });

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like as soon as the `Application_Start` method ends, that `WebSocketServer` is going to get out of scope and eventually garbage collected.

You could, set that object as member in the `Global` class, and dispose it on the `Application_End` event for example.

**UPDATE**:

You are also using the `wss` schema but not providing any certificate configuration. Please note that IIS and Fleck are two different things, that runs in different ports, and not because you create Fleck into the ASP.NET app means that Fleck is going to infer the SSL/TLS configuration or any configuration at all. Try to set the schema to `ws` instead and open the page without HTTPS and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I put `server` as global static variable. Then when I tested from browser console, it times out while connecting.